# Transparent image in fx button from css

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

Can I make the image transparent in the button through css?
Something like:

```
.button:disabled {
-fx-background-opacity-image:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is a JavaFX question and only answer if you know how to do this with [JavaFX CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), not HTML CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In your css use this :

```
.button > .image-view {
    -fx-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

It will target the image inside the button and style it (in this case : set opacity to 0.5)

Comment: Oh, it's for background images? Because in this case, you might need to use `-fx-background-color` and pass in a rgba value, like `rgba(240,240,240,0.5)`, the last component will be your opacity

Comment: Background color is the transparency for the color, not the image. And the image is on top of the color.

Comment: Then i'm afraid it won't be possible, afaik. Maybe you could try to change the image opacity directly in photoshop, paint.net or something, and use `-fx-background-color : transparent` to enable transparency in the css

Comment: This is understandable, but this is not my version of the solution

Answer (score -1):

You can use opacity property of CSS, it takes a value from 0.0 - 1.0

In your case-

```
.button:disabled {
   opacity :0.5;
}
```